# My app UI is not changing its orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

When i press Keypad 7 and 9 my emulator orientation is changing but my app orientation is not changing. Although my app's orientation is changing on a real device.
Why my app's orientation is not changing on emulator?
I have tried editing the emulator settings and changing it to landscape but still my app's orientation is not changing but only emulator's orientation is changing.

Comment: check your activity orientation inside manifest

Comment: I have not set the activity orientation in manifest file. It is changing orientation in real device but not in emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<activity
        android:name="your.package.name.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Mention this in your activity tag in manifest file

Comment: I have changed the manifest file. But screen still don't rotate.

Comment: Did u write any code for configuration in ur Activity ??

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_services);}